# brun's method and primitive roots

Tags: analytic-number-theory

let be $N(x) = \sum\limits_{d|p - 1} {\mu \left( d \right)} {F_x}(d)$ that $p$ is a prime number and ${F_x}(d) = \frac{{{x^2}}}{{4d}} + O(x{p^{\frac{1}{2}}})$
that $x+1=g(p)$ and $g(p)$ is the least primitive root modulo $p$. Applying Brun's method to $N(x)$ in conjunction with ${F_x}(d)$ in order to make a lower estimate for $N(x)$, one obtain 
$$N(x) > \frac{{{x^2}}}{4}\sum\limits_{} {\frac{{\mu (d)}}{d}}  + O({m^c}{p^{{\textstyle{1 \over 2}}}}x)$$
that $m$ is the number of distinct primes that divide $p-1$ and $c$ is a constant.can you explain these steps?also i dont know what is Brun's method.
for more details you can see [this](http://msp.org/pjm/1957/7-1/pjm-v7-n1-p05-s.pdf) (4.1) and (4.2)

Comment: Maybe they're referring to the Brun Sieve? Check out a book on additive number theory like Nathanson.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen can you explain how $N(x)>...$? specially that big oh.

Comment: @johnm can you?